# Does an 8" round to 10x3.25" elbow exist?

Tags: vent, exhaust-vent, hood

I have open space above cabinets and wife does not want a chimney on our range hood.

SO I am looking for an elbow that will take the 8" round vertical exhaust and go 90 degrees into a 10x3.25"  (we have ~4" of molding above cabinets)
[image]

I found this online, but it's not quite the right size.  Anyone know if there is a proper term for this I can search, or if I could get one to meet my specs?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a piece of 10x3.25 duct, cap off one end and cut an 8" hole in one side and add a flange to connect the 8" duct to.  These should be common parts that are easier to source than some exactly sized elbow that still might need modification.

Comment: thank you!  I guess without adding any additional height any elbow I find would essentially have the same airflow restriction/back-pressure from this sudden change .

Comment: You may be able to put some curved baffle inside this home-made option to help direct the airflow.  You can always put some more time into it - I just listed the basic idea.

Comment: Note that 10x3.25 has a cross section of  about 32.  8" round is more like 50 - so you will have a lot more restriction.

Comment: Thanks @MartinBonner!  The hood itself uses a 10x3.25 if venting horizontally, the 8" vertical is I think larger to allow the optional 2nd blower that we're not purchasing. So hopefully the flow will be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Go to any HVAC shop or duct fabricator, explain what you want and they may be able to make it to your specs.

Comment: Ah great point.  Some family friends have a local HVAC business here, but I never thought to ask them.

Comment: I was just at Home Depot yesterday and saw a 6" straight X 3 1/4" adapter near the appliance parts, if that will help.